# Why do I have creases when i subdivde my roundcube?

Tags: objects, subdivision-surface

Im kinda new to blender and I was following this tutorial on youtube and I did everything they did but when I subdivided my circle "round cube" it had creases in it. This didnt happen before when I did this tutorial and im not sure if its a settings thing or if i clicked on something I shouldnt have from when I used it last? for refrence its (2:51) in the video.[image]

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rEBwBrRzyhw

Comment: I've been unable to duplicate your problem from that tutorial using the settings your screenshot shows (if the Mirror modifier's Clipping or Merge are not checked it can cause the vertical crease, but yours are checked).  If you'd be willing to share your .blend file:  https://blend-exchange.com/help

Comment: There could be some duplicate vertices. Try merging them. M > By Distance.

Comment: Thank you! It fixed it :) @Leander

Answer (score 3):

Duplicate vertices (vertices, that are exactly on top of one another) will subdivide differently.
You can merge duplicate vertices with <kbd>M</kbd> > *By Distance*. If your normals are irregular after that operating, recalculate them <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>.